# Manually configuring and setting priority for network devices in a non-rooted Android 13 device via ADB

Tags: adb, usb, networking, android-13, ethernet

I'd like to configure and set priority for the different network interfaces on a device (Z Fold4) running Android 13, with multiple USB Ethernet devices, via ADB.

I'm basically looking for functionality similar to `ifconfig` (but you can't use `ifconfig` without root).